# merge two pandas dataframes and enter the matched entries in a column separated by a pipe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, match, delimiter

I have 2 large pandas dataframes `variants` and `phenotype` when mapped between dataframes on column `gene` it should print all rows of variants dataframe with a new column `HP-ID` separated by `pipe`. Here are few lines of the dataframe

```py
import pandas

# variants

data_var = {'CHROM': ['Chr1', 'Chr11'], 'START': [51937273, 56867846], 'GENE': ['KCNJ1', 'NPHS2'], 'REF': ['C', 'G'], 'ALT': ['T', 'A']}

variants = pd.DataFrame(data_var)

   CHROM     START   GENE REF ALT
0   Chr1  51937273  KCNJ1   C   T
1  Chr11  56867846  NPHS2   G   A

# phenotype

data_phe = {'entrez-id': [3758, 3758, 3758, 3758, 3758, 7827, 7827, 7827, 7827],
            'GENE': ['KCNJ1', 'KCNJ1', 'KCNJ1', 'KCNJ1', 'KCNJ1', 'NPHS2', 'NPHS2', 'NPHS2', 'NPHS2'],
            'HP-ID': ['HP:0002013', 'HP:0002007', 'HP:0001561', 'HP:0000256', 'HP:0001508', 'HP:0003774', 'HP:0003678', 'HP:0000093', 'HP:0003073'],
            'phenotype': ['Vomiting', 'Frontal bossing', 'Polyhydramnios', 'Macrocephaly', 'Failure to thrive', 'Stage 5 chronic kidney disease', 'Rapidly progressive', 'Proteinuria', 'Hypoalbuminemia']}


phenotype = pd.DataFrame(data_phe)

   entrez-id   GENE       HP-ID                       phenotype
0       3758  KCNJ1  HP:0002013                        Vomiting
1       3758  KCNJ1  HP:0002007                 Frontal bossing
2       3758  KCNJ1  HP:0001561                  Polyhydramnios
3       3758  KCNJ1  HP:0000256                    Macrocephaly
4       3758  KCNJ1  HP:0001508               Failure to thrive
5       7827  NPHS2  HP:0003774  Stage 5 chronic kidney disease
6       7827  NPHS2  HP:0003678             Rapidly progressive
7       7827  NPHS2  HP:0000093                     Proteinuria
8       7827  NPHS2  HP:0003073                 Hypoalbuminemia
```

**desired output**

```
CHROM  START  GENE  REF  ALT  HP-ID
Chr1  51937273  KCNJ1  C  T  HP:0002013|HP:0002007|HP:0001561|HP:0000256|HP:0001508
Chr6  56867846  NPHS2  G  A  HP:0003774|HP:0003678|HP:0000093|HP:0003073
```

What I have tired

```
data_frames = [variants, phenotype]
df_marged = reduce(lambda left,right: pd.merge(left,right,on=['GENE'],how='outer'), data_frames)
```

this prints all the rows of variants and phenotype, when matched one below the other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First aggregate `join` by [`GroupBy.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.agg.html) and then use [`DataFrame.merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html):

```
variants.merge(phenotype.groupby('GENE')['HP-ID'].agg('|'.join).reset_index(), on='GENE')
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, i need some help with a small change in your solution. when there is no match(data missing in the phenotype) it should be NA or blank. The entries in the variant dataframe should not be removed. Thank you

Comment: @Luffy - So you need left join -  `variants.merge(phenotype.groupby('GENE')['HP-ID'].agg('|'.join).reset_index(), on='GENE', how='left')` ?